# kohana 2 hooks mobile redirect

Tags: hook, kohana, mobile-website

I placed a mobile hook in the hook directory to look for mobile devices and redirect to the appropriate controller. My question is if I want to put a link on the mobile pages to have the option to view the full site. How would by pass the hook. What is the correct way for this to be accomplished..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of options:

1) When you redirect to the mobile site add a url parameter that the mobile controller will check for and add the appropriate link back to the full site. Eg redirect to http://m.yoursite.ext/?fromFullSite

2) The mobile controller can look for the referer in the $_SERVER headers and see if the user came in from the full site, eg

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'http://yoursite.ext/') === 0) { 
    //was redirected, add link
}
```